# The literal xyz of type int is out of range

Tags: java, int, long-integer

I am working with data types at the moment in Java, and if I have understood correctly the type `long` accepts a value between the ranges of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Now as you can see below, I have create a `long` variable called `testLong`, although when I insert 9223372036854775807 as the value, I get an error stating:

> The literal 9223372036854775807  of the type int is out of range.

I don't know why it is referring to the `long` data type as an `int`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Code:

```
char testChar = 01;
byte testByte = -128;
int testInt = -2147483648;
short testShort = -32768;
long testLong = 9223372036854775807;
float testFoat;
double testDouble = 4.940656458412;
boolean testBool = true;
```

Comment: By the way: what compiler are you using? Both Eclipse and the Sun JDK compiler give different (in my opinion better) error messages for this problem.

Answer (score 220):

Add a capital `L` to the end:

```
long value = 9223372036854775807L;
```

Otherwise, the compiler will try to parse the literal as an `int`, hence the error message

Comment: It's in the Java language specs. Find the full text [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html)

Comment: @Lukas, long value= 00000077029062100L; gives me the same error, and it is less than 19 digits. any Idea why it is throwing "The literal 0000007702062100L of type long is out of range "

Comment: @SantosshKumhar: That's an [octal literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), which cannot contain digits `8` or `9`. Remove the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 58):

> I don't know why it is referring to the long data type as an int

It is not. You should learn to trust compiler messages (especially when they are from sane, modern compilers and not ancient compilers that tended to have bad error messages). While the language that they speak might be hard to decipher at times, they are not usually lying to you.

Let's look at it again:

> The literal of int 9223372036854775807 is out of range.

Note, that it **doesn't** mention your variable `testLong` or the type `long` anywhere, so the problem is **not** about the initialization. It seems to occur at some other point.

Now lets investigate some of the parts of the message:

- `int` tells us that he wants to treat something as an `int` value (which is not what you wanted!)
- "out of range" is pretty clear: something is not within the expected range (probably that of `int`)
- "The literal": now that's interesting: what is a literal?

I'll leave the cozy list to talk about literals for a moment: literals are places where you have some value in your code. There are `String` literals, `int` literals, `class` literals and so on. Every time you mention a *value* explicitly in your code, it's a literal.

So it's not actually nagging you about the variable declaration, but the number itself, the value is what it's nagging you about.

You can easily verify this by using the same literal in a context where a `long` and an `int` are equally acceptable:

```
System.out.println(9223372036854775807);
```

`PrintStream.println` can take either [an `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29) or [a `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28long%29) (or pretty much anything else). So that code should be fine, right?

No. Well, maybe it *should* be, but according to the rules it **is** not fine.

The problem is [that "some digits" is defined to be an `int` literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) and therefore **must** be in the range defined by `int`.

If you want to write a `long` literal, then you must make that explicit by appending the `L` (or lower case `l`, but I **highly** suggest you always use the upper-case variant, because it's much easier to read and harder to mistake for a `1`).

Note that a similar problem occurs with `float` (postfix `F`/`f`) and `double` (postfix `D`/`d`).

*Side note:* you'll realize that there are no `byte` or `short` literals and you can still assign values (usually `int` literals) to `byte` and `short` variables: that's possible due to special rules in [§ 5.2 about conversions in an Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2): they allow assignment of constant expressions of a larger type to `byte`, `short`, `char` or `int` *if* the values are within the types range.

Comment: Where do you take the time from ;-)

Comment: @Lukas: I occasionally write such answers in the hope that I won't have to write 300 shorter ones for it ;-) Also: helping to interpret the error message (hopefully) means less "what does that error message mean" questions.

Comment: your answer is very good... no  doubt, that's why up-vote, but please edit it and at top(start of your answer), just write in 1 line the exact solution to the problem, and  then below your explanation. Because lot of people search for quick solution rather than deep explanation

Comment: They are free to look at other second answers (the highest-voted one even gives the quick solution). I think that educating people on how to parse and understand error messages is more useful in the long run than just doing it for them. "Give a man a fish..." and all that.

Answer (score 24):

Try doing `9223372036854775807L`. The `L` at the end tells Java that `9223372036854775807` is a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past and I fixed that by writing the value in the scientific form.
for example:

```
double val = 9e300;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
long ak = 34778754226788444L/l;
```

Both use but at a time only one use uppercase L or lowercase l.

Why use L/l? Because long is a part of  integral datatype.