# Assigning a value to long data type in java - defaulting to int

Tags: java, long-integer

```
long val = 5000000000;
```

The error during this assignment is:

> The literal 5000000000 of type int is out of range

Why does the compiler by default assume the literal to be type `int` when it is declared with type `long`?

Comment: read the section [integer literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in this tutorial

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
long val = 5000000000L;
```

Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093186/the-literal-of-int-xxxxx-is-out-of-range)

Comment: Oops did not see this answer when I wrote my answer.

Comment: +1 , @MansoorShaikh No issues,Just explain in brief why you added L,then your answer should be valid :)

Answer (score 7):

There is aspecific suffixes for long i.e `L`. If there is no suffix, then 5000000000 assumed to be an `int` type. And 5000000000 is out of `int` range, causing the erro. So you need to add `L` at the end of 5000000000 for it to be treated as a `long` value. Change your declaration from

```
long val = 5000000000;
```

to

```
long val = 5000000000L;
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the letter L at the end of your number as shown below

long val = 5000000000L;

Answer (score 4):

long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).

You should append 'l' or 'L' to the value explicitly used to initialize the variable; even as small as 0.

```
 long val = 0L;
```