# Gcm sender id is out of range

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create an xmpp gcm server.
The project number generated by gcm is greater than the range of long. what should i do?
Does using project id help?
But the project id is not integer.
Also the max value of long is 2^63 which is larger than the project number generated. still i am getting the error in eclipse

```
final long senderId = 908*********;
```

error that i get:-

```
The literal 908********* of type int is out of range
```

Comment: Please add your code.  This question is too broad at the moment to even try to answer.

Comment: do i need to add more code @EricHauenstein . The project number is a 12 digit integer

Answer (score 0):

Appended `L` at the end of the integer project number and got it working.

For more detail see-
[The literal of int xxxxx is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093186/the-literal-of-int-xxxxx-is-out-of-range)