# Project Euler #3 out of integer range java

Tags: java, integer, arithmeticexception

The code is supposed to give back the biggest prime number.
More about the task here: https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

```
int checkFactors(double na) {

        long n = (long) na;
        int biggestPrimeFactor = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (n % i == 0 && isPrimFaktor(i) && i > biggestPrimeFactor)
                biggestPrimeFactor = i;

        return biggestPrimeFactor;
    }

boolean isPrimeFactor(int n) {

        int length= 0;
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
            if (n % i == 0)
                length++;

        if (length== 2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I decided to make the parameter of checkFactors() a double because I tried to test why my code didn't work properly.

```
System.out.println(checkFactors(13195));
```

works and returns "29".

However, `System.out.println(checkFactors(600851475143));`
does not work,

"600851475143 of type int is out of range".

```
System.out.println(checkFactors(600851475143.0));
```

does compile but gives me after a couple of seconds an ArithmeticException.

Comment: Why don't you use a bigger Datatype like EG long or Biginteger?

Comment: Look here, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093186/the-literal-of-int-xxxxx-is-out-of-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`600851475143 of type int is out of range`

- This number is bigger than `int` can store. Appending `.0` to the number converts the number into a `double` which *can* represent that number
- Instead of `.0` you can do `checkFactors(600851475143d)` which ensure the number is a double and not an int

Answer (score 1):

Use long as a data type for na and also biggestPrimeFactor. The values are too large for storing in an int variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make Your parameter back to `long` and make letter `L` after your large number  like this `600851475143L`, I think it will work