# claims long is out of bounds

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to declare a 'long' variable in my main function in netBeans IDE 11.3. For some reason it claims that any of the numbers I'm writing is out of bounds when it clearly shouldn't be. All numbers of this size is apparently out of bounds:

```
long x = 190979266074733;
```

This is nowhere near the maximum number (2^63 - 1), can someone tell why this isn't allowed? I can get around it by dividing the number into factors and multiply them. It doesnt complain and it print out the correct value.

```
long p = 15485863;
long q = 12332491;
long n = p*q;
```

this is allowed appently. But I need the long to be one single number, not divided like that. how can I make netBeans accept it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The literal xyz of type int is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093186/the-literal-xyz-of-type-int-is-out-of-range)

Comment: Netbeans is only correctly implementing the Java specification.  If Netbeans says your code is invalid, then it *really is* invalid.  You can't make it accept invalid code .

Comment: For the record, [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) states: "It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; *or if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2^31)*."

Comment: thank you Turamart for linking me to a simulair problem. Writing a 'L' to the end of my long x = 190979266074733L;
whas the thing I was missing. Java must have interpreted 'x' as an 'int' even though i decleared it as a 'long'. now it works.